# combine two phpmysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to combine these two php mysql queries and want to get one resultset array.
first query gives all members and postby related posts and second query gives all admin related posts with `member_id` is 0 and `post_by` with 0 and `admin_id` is not 0 and `super_admin_post` 0.

Database: 
1) wall_post_master this my first database fields.
`wp_id`, `wp_cat_id`, `wl_text`, `wp_img`, `datetime`, `displevel`, `mg_id`, `member_id`, `admin_id`, `family_id`, `post_by`, `photo_id`, `post_category`, `generation_id`, `visible_to`, `highlight`, `super_admin_post`

2) admin_user_master this my second database fields.
`user_id`, `family_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email_id`, `user_level`

Here my conditions to show wallpost data:
1)if mg_id exits with multiple member_id relates to comma.
2)if visible_to exits with multiple member_id relates to comma.
3)if member_id exits with current member_id.
4)if member_id exits in post_by.
5)if member_id is 0 and post_by is 0 and super_admin_post = 0 then i want to display as admin post.

First Query:

```
$grpsearch = "";
foreach ($arrseltran as $grpid) {
    $grpsearch .= " OR ( FIND_IN_SET('" . $grpid . "', wp.mg_id) AND displevel = 3)";
}
if($time == ""){ $time .= " WHERE"; }else{ $time .=" AND"; }
$time .= "
    wp.family_id = " . $_SESSION['logft']['family_id'] . " AND
    wp.post_category = 0 AND  
    ( 
        wp.member_id = " . $_SESSION['logft']['member_id'] . " OR 
        wp.post_by = " . $_SESSION['logft']['member_id'] . " OR 
        FIND_IN_SET('" . $_SESSION['logft']['member_id'] . "', wp.visible_to) " . $grpsearch . " OR 
        displevel = 1 
    )";

$timeline = "SELECT wp.*, 
wp.member_id, 
wp.datetime AS TimeSpent,
wp_cat.font_color,
photo.photo_path, 
mm.first_name,
mm.middle_name,
mm.last_name,
mm1.first_name AS to_first_name,
mm1.middle_name AS to_middle_name, 
mm1.last_name AS to_last_name
FROM wall_post_master wp 
INNER JOIN 
    wallpost_cat_master wp_cat ON wp_cat.wp_cat_id = wp.wp_cat_id
INNER JOIN 
    member_master mm ON mm.member_id = (CASE WHEN (wp.post_by = 0) THEN wp.member_id ELSE wp.post_by END)
INNER JOIN 
    member_master mm1 ON mm1.member_id = wp.member_id
LEFT JOIN 
    photo_master photo ON photo.photo_id = mm.photo_id
" . $time ." ORDER BY Timespent DESC";
```

Second Query:

```
$timeline1 = "SELECT wpa.*, 
wpa.family_id, 
wpa.datetime AS TimeSpent,
wp_cat.font_color,
wpa.wp_img,
c.family_id,
c.family_name,
c.editor_photo,
aum.first_name,
aum.last_name
FROM wall_post_master wpa 
INNER JOIN 
    wallpost_cat_master wp_cat ON wp_cat.wp_cat_id = wpa.wp_cat_id
INNER JOIN 
    config c ON c.family_id = wpa.family_id
INNER JOIN
    admin_user_master aum ON aum.family_id = wpa.family_id
where 
    aum.user_level = 1 and 
    wpa.admin_id <> 0 and 
    wpa.family_id='".$_SESSION['logft']['family_id']."' and 
    wpa.member_id=0 and 
    wpa.post_by=0  and 
    wpa.super_admin_post=0 
ORDER 
  BY Timespent DESC";
```

Comment: Is `UNION` what you're looking for?

Comment: i tryed union but not working at all because first query depend on member_id or post_by viseversa (CASE WHEN (wp.post_by = 0) THEN wp.member_id ELSE wp.post_by END), second query if member_id and post_by both are 0 then its family admin post display to all members so i want to join both the query in one resultset with decending timestamp.

Comment: Could you show some sample data, and what you're trying to get as the result of the combined query?

Comment: here my 5 conditions for showing wall post data.

Answer (score 0):

Use concept of [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) itself

```
select a.col1,a.col2,b.col1,b.col3 from first_table as a, second_table as b where a.col1=condition and b.col1=condition
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqli function:

```
mysqli_multi_query()
```

or

```
mysqli::multi_query()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

full example from link:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
Procedural style

<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What's the benefit of multi query over just doing two queries?

Comment: you save connection and authentication time, (and this is long time compared with query process time)

Comment: Authentication only happens when you call `new mysqli`, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Anyway, what I think he's actually looking for is how to combine them into one query using `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar no, you authenticate each time you send query to DB

Comment: DB authenticate you each time you send new query

Comment: What about SQL Injection? I believe it is easier to inject something if they use `mysqli::multi_query()`

Comment: @Bluedayz no, if you validate it before send query

Comment: You can still attack a database even though only prepared statements are used. It should be even easier if you use `mysqli::multi_query()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

if you match up the names of the fields selected in both queries you caan also use UNION

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx